# Spring Data JPA emojis are coming as ? rather than actual emoji

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to read the data from My SQL using Spring Boot and JPA. One of the column data is having emojis. 
After setting the connection url with useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8, it is able to get the basic emojis correctly such as ✅. However, it doesn't work with Hatching Chick () emoji instead it gives ?. The sql server and the table column has been set with correct character encoding configuration:
text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL.

Basically Srping JPA is not supporting Unicode version 6.0 or later in my case.

Any idea what I am missing here please? Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

Follow the tutorial at https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4. Basically you need to configure your MySQL my.cnf file as well set the `spring.datasource.initSQL=SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'` option in your application.properties.